# Spring Boot and Keycoak redirect loop, followed by 400 and "no state cookie"

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

This is driving me absolutely insane.

I'm trying to set up the most basic authentication with Spring Boot and Keycloak. Everything works fine until I actually log in through the realm login screen. I get redirected back to the secured location, and then back to keycloak auth page, and back to secured location (as I'm already authenticated). At the end I get to 400 page and see the following warning in my log:

```
2020-06-08 15:36:38.646  WARN 12028 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : No state cookie
```

Sometimes I get err_to_many_redirects.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sso-demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>sso-demo-app1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring.boot.version>2.3.0.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
                <version>10.0.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties:

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://keycloakserver/auth
keycloak.realm=Realm Name
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.resource=demo-login-app
keycloak.ssl-required=external

keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[0]=test-user-role
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/secured


server.port=8080
```

Config:

```
@Configuration
public class KeycloakConfig {

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/secured")
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping
    public String mainController(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Model model) {
            return "secured.html";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem due to the realm name being configured incorrectly.

First I named my realm "Main Realm Name". I think the problem here were the spaces.

The second time when I tested on the master realm, I had specified "Master" as opposed to "master" in the application properties file.

configuring the realm name to "MainRealmName" fixed the issue